# Count XML elements and echo as much results as the xml elements counted

Tags: php, html, xml

I would like some help with an issue I have. I parse some data from and XML API using PHP. 
This is my code:

```
<?php
$gigatools = simplexml_load_file('http://gigs.gigatools.com/u/A2LTD.xml');
echo "<table id='gigs_parse'>\n";

for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {

    $event = $gigatools->event[$i];
    $day=$event->day;
    $month=$event->month;
    $name=$event->name;
    $venue=$event->venue;
    $city=$event->city;
    $country=$event->country;
    $image=$event->image; 

        if($month == 1){
        $maand = 'JAN';
        } else if($month == 2){
        $maand = 'FEB';
        } else if($month == 3){
        $maand = 'MAR';
        } else if($month == 4){
        $maand = 'APR';
        } else if($month == 5){
        $maand = 'MAY';
        } else if($month == 6){
        $maand = 'JUN';
        } else if($month == 7){
        $maand = 'JUL';
        } else if($month == 8){
        $maand = 'AUG';
        } else if($month == 9){
        $maand = 'SEP';
        } else if($month == 10){
        $maand = 'OCT';
        } else if($month == 11){
        $maand = 'NOV';
        } else if($month == 12){
        $maand = 'DEC';
    }

echo "<tr cellspacing='60' class='row'><td class='date'><span>",$day,"</span><br/>",$maand,"</td>\n";
echo "<td class='party'>",$name,"</td>\n";
echo "<td class='location'>",$venue,", ",$city,", ",$country,"</td>\n";

echo "<td class='image'>"."<img src='".$image."'>"."</td>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

As you can see, I am using "for" to get 12 results. This is pretty static and it leads to missing some information or giving me some empty cells. What I would like to do is to get as much results as the event elements on the [API](http://gigs.gigatools.com/u/A2LTD.xml) . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleXML's count` method.

Here's an example :-

```
<?php
$fileHandler = simplexml_load_file("A2LTD.xml");
var_dump($fileHandler->event->count());
?>
```

For your file, the above code will return `9`, which is the number of nodes with parent `event`.

Comment: Thank you very much. After that I guess I keep my code as is except the for part. I assume I will do a foreach ($fileHandler as $fileHandler)

Comment: No, for that you'd need to do a simple for loop.
`for($i=0;$i<=intval($fileHandler->event->count());$i++)
{
//access using $fileHandler->event[$i]
}`

Comment: Thanks again, everything works fine. Just 2 small issues I can't figure out. First, I get an int(9) on top of my table. And second I get an extra event. It counts 9 but I get 10. No need to answer since you've alreadt helped a lot.

Comment: For your first issue, remove the `var_dump` line, then, you can run your for loop like :-
`for($i=0;$i<intval($fileHandler->event->count());$i++) { //access using $fileHandler->event[$i] }`